# Apache flink metaspace exception while running job several times

Tags: out-of-memory, apache-flink, mat, grpc-java, metaspace

I'm working on fixing the issue "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace"
in the time of running an flink job via "Submit new job" web interface several times.

My flink job gets data from gRpc service usig grpc-java.  After press submit job button several times I got OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIfpV.png)

After research I've found out that every org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader wasn't cleared by GC.
My job was launched 4 times and MAT shows me 4 ChildFirstClassLoader in Dominator tree.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOzS7.png)

Using MAT(Path to GC Roots exclude all phantom/weak/soft/etc) I tried to found out who keeps ClassLoaders alive. But 0 paths was found on every ChildFirstClassLoader. It looks like nobody keeps ClassLoaders and they are ready to be collected by GC but It didn't happen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ6dX.png)

Any ideas how to find a reason?

Comment: Are you using the Hadoop file system? Assuming not, but if so then I've run into a similar issue that I had to work around.